# car rental secondary coverage is enough?

Tags: car-insurance, american-express

I rented car by Amex and it gives you [car insurance](https://www.americanexpress.com/us/credit-cards/benefits/detail/car-rental-insurance/delta-gold). But this has only secondary coverage:

> This benefit provides secondary coverage and does not cover liability,
>   damages to vehicles other than those rented by the Card Member, and
>   injuries to people in other vehicles.

But [here is written](https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/car-rental-insurance-coverage-1273.php):

> If you don’t have personal auto insurance or if you’re renting a car
>   in a country where your personal auto insurance isn’t in effect, then
>   any card that offers secondary coverage becomes primary, so it should
>   theoretically cover the entire cost of the damage.

So, I don't have personal auto insurance, doesn't it mean I don't need to buy additional primary coverage (from Amex), because it's already covered?

I just want to understand does it makes sense to buy Amex primary insurance if I already have it?

Comment: @HartCO, so my question is: what does it cover?

Comment: It covers the cost to repair/replace the rental car, plus the lost revenue to the rental company while the car is out of service. It also provides some medical/accidental death benefit to you and/or your passengers, and covers some loss/damage of you/your passengers personal property.

Comment: @HartCO, but do I have primary coverage?

Comment: it's written: any card that offers secondary coverage becomes primary if you don't have personal auto insurance.

Comment: You're right, not certain if that is accurate, but either way liability isn't covered, and that is essential.

Comment: but if I buy Amex primary insurance, it will be the same?

Comment: I'm not familiar with their products, but it looks like even the premium component doesn't include liability:  https://feeservices.americanexpress.com/premium/car-rental-insurance-coverage/home.do

Comment: The distinction of primary/secondary has nothing to do with what is covered by the insurance, it only affects which company has first obligation to pay for the items they cover. Someone else may know better, but I would imagine there's a better insurance product out there for people who just need coverage for a rental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That Amex cover may become 'primary' if you have no other insurance, but it still won't cover

> liability, damages to vehicles other than those rented by the Card Member, and injuries to people in other vehicles

It'll only cover damage to the car you're renting, lost revenue to the rental company, some medical/accidental death benefit to you and/or your passengers, and some loss/damage of you/your passengers personal property.

The Amex being 'primary' means that  you don't have to report any incidents to another insurer first, and that Amex will cover the full amount of whatever is covered (up to whatever limits might be in place).
If you had other insurance, then the Amex would be secondary, and you would have to report to and claim from that other insurance before Amex would step in to pick up any leftovers (but they still wouldn't cover anything in the excluded list above).

**Some content shamelessly plagiarized from HartCO's comments.

Comment: As I understood primary covers everything? The I'm wrong? And if I buy primary insurance from Amex, it doesn't do any difference?

Comment: I just want to understand does it makes sense to buy Amex primary insurance if I already have it?

Comment: **'Primary' does _not_ mean 'covers everything'**. It means 'go to this insurer first when you are involved in an incident'. They then assess everything and pay out whatever is covered. If there are other things not covered by the primary insurer or the damage exceeds the primary insurer's coverage limits, then you go talk to your secondary insurer (if you have one) or pay from your own pocket.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://thepointsguy.com/2016/05/secondary-car-rental-insurance-works-for-renters-without-auto-insurance/) suggests there is an Amex with a liability benefit:

> However, one thing to note is that both primary and secondary coverage only insure damage to the rental vehicle and are not all-inclusive. Things such as personal injury, personal liability and damage to other vehicles and personal property are not covered under either car rental benefit. As per various sources (as well as agents at the car rental desk), apparently the only card that offers liability coverage on a rental by default is the American Express Centurion (Black) Card. Even American Express’ optional Premium Car Rental Protection doesn’t cover liability.

Comment: so, if I don't have Centurion (Black) Card, there is no way to get liability benefit from Amex